# Exception using Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to use Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button bBuscarWEb; 


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        bBuscarWEb = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bBuscarWeb);

        bBuscarWEb.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view){
                buscarWeb(null);
            }
        });


    }
    public void buscarWeb(View view) {
        String query = "coche";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
        intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, query); // query contains search string
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

But I always get this exception:

> 02-27 10:24:38.549 21392-21392/intenciones.example.org.intenciones
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                        Process: intenciones.example.org.intenciones, PID: 21392
>                                                                                        android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   Intent { act=android.intent.action.WEB_SEARCH (has extras) }
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1660)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1430)
>                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3532)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
>                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3493)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
>                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3735)
>                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3703)
>                                                                                            at
>   intenciones.example.org.intenciones.MainActivity.buscarWeb(MainActivity.java:96)
>                                                                                            at
>   intenciones.example.org.intenciones.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:39)
>                                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
>                                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19270)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
>                                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Does anyone know what is happening and who to solve this problem?
Thanks and best regards,

Comment: From the exception, you dont have any internet browsing app.

Comment: Hi Abilash, yes you are right, I didn't realize I had the google search app disable. Thanks for your help